# What does the "%%bash" command do in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

This is from a Python notebook on the google cloud platform guides.

Can you please explain to me how to interpret and understand this code?

```
%%bash
export PROJECT=$(gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)")
echo "Your current GCP Project Name is: "$PROJECT
```

It gives the following output:

```
Your current GCP Project Name is: cpb123-123123
```

Comment: it means it is `bash` code and it executes it with `bash`.

Comment: What does that mean? What is bash? Some kind of console?  I don't know what bash is and how it works.

Comment: `bash` is Linux shell to execute commans - like `cmd.exe` in Windows. it is often names `console` or `terminal` but better name is `shell`

Comment: okay thank you all, now it's more clear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GNU Bash or simply Bash is a Unix shell and command language.

```
%%bash
```

Means, that the following code will be executed by bash.

In bash `$()` means it will return with the result of the commands inside the parentheses, in this case the commands are:

```
gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)"
```

Google cloud has its own command set to control your projects. This command will give you the core project you are working on.

```
export PROJECT=$(gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)")
echo "Your current GCP Project Name is: "$PROJECT
```

The export command in bash is used to set values to environmental variables. In the case it basically sets the value of an environmental variable called `PROJECT` and the echo just echoes the value back to the console.

You can find more on bash [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)).

Comment: The `%%` magic commands are not a feature of Python itself; they are implemented by the `ipython` interpreter which is what runs inside most notebooks.